# How to transform JSON file data directly in a Azure Data Factory pipeline

Tags: arrays, json, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I want to copy a JSON file into Azure SQL table, but it has nested Hierarchy, I only need the fields/values of the fields Ergon_Businessunit_code, KPL, Ergon_Functiegroep_code, Aantal.
How to do that? I tried with lookup en foreach, but got array errors

[image]

Comment: Add a data flow activity to your pipeline and use the Flatten transformation

Answer (score 2):

Yes as Mark Kromer mentioned, you can copy JSON data to the Azure SQL table using the `dataflow` activity.

Here are the steps to copy **JSON** to **Azure SQL** using dataflow:

1. Create a **JSON** **dataset** and connect it to the source.

[image]

2. **Source** data preview:

[image]

3. Connect the source output to `flatten` transformation and under Unroll by and Unroll root, select "**rows**" array.
4. You can remove the columns which not required to pass to the sink.

[image]

5. **Data preview** after it is flattened.

[image]

6. Add **sink** transformation and connect to Azure SQL table dataset.

[image]

7. In **mapping**, add or remove mapping as per the output columns.

[image]

8. **Output** data of sink.

[image]

9. Add the `dataflow` activity to the **pipeline** and execute it.

[image]

10. Data loaded to **Azure SQL table**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! I have one more question: is it possible to make the mapping in Step 4 dynamic, in case I want to process multiple files, all with the same JSON hierarchy (skip -1, take -1, rows), but differerent columns?

Comment: Is your sink table same for all these source files?

Comment: No, each source JSON file goes to its own destination sink table

Comment: Yes you can, just select the rows array in flatten instead of columns. Updates screenshot of flatten (step 4) to select rows array.

Comment: The, when validating, the sink gives the error:
"The following columns have a complex structure that can only be written to REST, ORC, JSON, AVRO, and Azure Cosmos DB: 'rows'. Delete the columns or update the sink to REST, ORC, JSON, AVRO, or Azure Cosmos DB."

Comment: the probleem seems to be that I Cannot do Unroll by rows, in the Flatten step, because The source loosens its projection when using a Parameterized source dataset. Apparently Flatten neede Rows to be in the Source Projection...

Comment: test comment123